# How to check is robospice loading some task

Tags: android, robospice

How to check is robospice load some task?
There's method `void addListenerIfPending()`. It will be very great if the method returns boolean value to check should i set progress bar in activity either to loading state or not after recreating.

For clarify, imagine that i have an activity with button and progress bar. 
When user clicks on button progress bar changes its state to loading. 
If i rotate device while loading i should to set listener again and check is task loading for set progress bar state to loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is in progress: [PR #383](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/pull/383) (you can check issue [#335](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/335) as well). I think it will be released with the next version, but there is no time estimation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's very weird that they didn't implement this yet. Can you answer on the same question, but about RxJava ?

Comment: RxJava, from what I know, works on a different level than RoboSpice. If you implement async behavior yourself using RxJava, you will have much more low-level work to do, but also more flexibility. I don't think the same question is applicable for RxJava.